# Change default cmd python version on windows10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I am using windows 10 and my default python version was python3 in a specific anaconda enviroment:

The command:

```
C:\Users\isp>where python
```

Returns:

```
C:\Users\isp\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I installed python2.7 (I need it for some purposes) and now I want to change the default python. How can I do this?

Comment: Does Anaconda associate .py files with Python 3's py.exe launcher? If so, you have shebang support for running scripts directly at the command line or in Explorer, without having to explicitly run python.exe. You can use an explicit shebang such as `#!C:\Users\isp\Anaconda3\python.exe` or a virtual one such as `#!python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python`.